# Not getting hiddenfield value after coming back from another page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have two pages called `test1.aspx` and `test2.aspx`.

In the `test1.aspx` there are some hidden fields.

I am first storing some value to all hidden fields and redirecting to another page called `test2.aspx`. when I am coming back to `test1.aspx`, I am losing the values of hidden fields.

How can i make the values of hidden field as it is even after coming back from another page. I can't use session or any other server side state management techniques.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Server.Transfer or Reponse.Redirect to navigate to the next page?

Reponse.Redirect destroys the history of the current page in the web server, while Server.Transfer keep the history.

Try: Server.Transfer("test1.aspx")

Enjoy ;-)

Comment: I am redirecting to another page using anchor tag href property and setting the values to hidden field on click event of that anchor tag.